# How to perform multiple t.tests with R package srvyr?

Tags: r, survey, weighted, t-test

As a follow up on a recent SO question (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63782975/10656562)) I am wondering how to perform multiple t.tests in `R` with weighted data  (package `srvyr`). I cant make it run and would be happy if anyone could help me here. I added a random sample in the code below.
Many thanks!

```
      #create data
      surveydata <- as.data.frame(replicate(1,sample(1:5,1000,rep=TRUE)))
      colnames(surveydata)[1] <- "q1"
      surveydata$q2 <- sample(6, size = nrow(surveydata), replace = TRUE)
      surveydata$q3 <- sample(6, size = nrow(surveydata), replace = TRUE)
      surveydata$q4 <- sample(6, size = nrow(surveydata), replace = TRUE)
      surveydata$group <- c(1,2)
      
      #replace all value "6" wir NA
      surveydata[surveydata == 6] <- NA
      
      #add NAs to group 1 in q1
      surveydata$q1[which(surveydata$q1==1 & surveydata$group==1)] = NA
      surveydata$q1[which(surveydata$q1==2 & surveydata$group==1)] = NA
      surveydata$q1[which(surveydata$q1==3 & surveydata$group==1)] = NA
      surveydata$q1[which(surveydata$q1==4 & surveydata$group==1)] = NA
      surveydata$q1[which(surveydata$q1==5 & surveydata$group==1)] = NA
      
      #add weights
      surveydata$weights <- round(runif(nrow(surveydata), min=0.2, max=1.5), 3)

      #create vector for relevant questions
                rquest <- names(surveydata)[1:4]


              
      # create survey design
                library(srvyr)
                surveydesign <- surveydata %>%
                          as_survey_design(strata = group, weights = weights, variables = c("group", all_of(rquest)))
      


      # perform multiple t.test (doesn't work yet)
                outcome <- do.call(rbind, lapply(names(surveydesign$variables)[-1], function(i) {
                          tryCatch({
                                    test <- t.test(as.formula(paste(i, "~ survey")), data = surveydesign)
                                    data.frame(question = i, 
                                               group1 = test$estimate[1], 
                                               group2 = test$estimate[2], 
                                               difference = diff(test$estimate),
                                               p_value = test$p.value, row.names = 1)
                          }, error = function(e) {
                                    data.frame(question = i, 
                                               group1 = NA,
                                               group2 = NA, 
                                               difference = NA,
                                               p_value = NA, row.names = 1)
                          })
                }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you have a series of question columns  in the example q1 to q4.  You've used `srvyr` to generate a `weights` column.  It is possible in our data that for a particular question one entire group maybe all `NA` and you'd like to generate results into a df even when that is true.  You want a `weighted Student's t-test` making use of the `weights` column not a simple t-test.  The only function I found that provides that is `weights::wtd.t.test` which doesn't offer a formula interface but wants to be fed vectors.

In order of steps taken:

1. Load requisite libraries

```r
library(srvyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(weights)
```

2. Build a custom function that removes the `NA`s by variable, `pull`s the vectors for `x`, `y`, `weightx`, `weighty`, runs the test, and extracts the info you want into a df row.

```r
multiple_wt_ttest <- function(i) {
   i <- ensym(i)
   xxx <- surveydata %>% 
      filter(!is.na(!!i)) %>% 
      split(.$group)
   newx <- pull(xxx[[1]], i)
   newy <- pull(xxx[[2]], i)
   wtx <- pull(xxx[[1]], weights)
   wty <- pull(xxx[[2]], weights)
   test <- wtd.t.test(x = newx, 
                      y = newy, 
                      weight = wtx, 
                      weighty = wty, 
                      samedata = FALSE)
   data.frame(question = rlang::as_name(i), 
              group1 = test$additional[[2]],
              group2 = test$additional[[3]], 
              difference = test$additional[[1]],
              p.value = test$coefficients[[3]])
}
```

3. Once we have the function we can use `lapply` to apply it column by column (notice it handles the case in `q2` where `group == 1` is all `NA`.

```r
lapply(names(surveydata)[1:4], multiple_wt_ttest)
#> [[1]]
#>   question group1   group2 difference p.value
#> 1       q1    NaN 3.010457        NaN      NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   question   group1   group2  difference  p.value
#> 1       q2 3.009003 3.071842 -0.06283922 0.515789
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   question   group1   group2 difference   p.value
#> 1       q3 2.985096 2.968867  0.0162288 0.8734034
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   question   group1   group2 difference    p.value
#> 1       q4 2.856255 3.047787 -0.1915322 0.04290471
```

4. Finally, wrap it in a `do.call` and `rbind` to make the df you desire

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(surveydata)[1:4], multiple_wt_ttest))
#>   question   group1   group2  difference    p.value
#> 1       q1      NaN 3.010457         NaN         NA
#> 2       q2 3.009003 3.071842 -0.06283922 0.51578905
#> 3       q3 2.985096 2.968867  0.01622880 0.87340343
#> 4       q4 2.856255 3.047787 -0.19153218 0.04290471
```

Your data (without showing all the gyrations to create it and heading the first 200 rows)

```r
surveydata <- 
structure(list(q1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, NA, 5L, 
NA, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, 
NA, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L, 
NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, NA, 5L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, 
NA, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, 
NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L, NA, 2L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, 
NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L), q2 = c(NA, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, NA, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, NA, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, NA, 5L, 2L, 
NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, NA, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, NA, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, NA, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, NA, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L), q3 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, NA, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, NA, NA, 3L, 5L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, NA, 5L, 
2L, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 4L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, NA, 2L, 1L, 3L, NA, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, NA, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, NA, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, NA, 1L, 
4L), q4 = c(NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, NA, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, NA, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 
5L, NA, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, NA, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 1L, 3L), group = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    weights = c(1.445, 0.408, 0.621, 0.961, 1.492, 0.625, 1.131, 
    0.246, 0.612, 0.621, 1.311, 0.649, 1.282, 0.898, 1.268, 0.641, 
    0.764, 0.759, 0.306, 0.707, 0.899, 0.785, 1.279, 0.458, 0.882, 
    0.384, 1.492, 0.468, 0.785, 0.707, 0.489, 1.113, 0.692, 0.293, 
    0.642, 1.327, 0.362, 1.405, 1.173, 0.732, 0.661, 0.522, 1.001, 
    0.374, 1.181, 0.819, 1.389, 0.43, 0.477, 0.879, 0.634, 0.417, 
    0.359, 1.007, 0.866, 0.203, 1.469, 0.294, 1.326, 1.391, 0.871, 
    1.036, 1.251, 0.417, 1.074, 1.268, 0.963, 0.469, 0.215, 1.074, 
    0.644, 1.054, 0.787, 0.714, 0.568, 0.397, 1.421, 0.692, 0.262, 
    0.644, 0.793, 0.808, 0.25, 0.842, 1.039, 0.359, 0.987, 1.257, 
    0.301, 0.203, 0.823, 1.328, 1.192, 0.256, 1.099, 0.668, 1.129, 
    0.413, 0.266, 1.121, 0.893, 1.484, 0.568, 1.255, 0.531, 0.461, 
    0.773, 0.298, 0.233, 0.676, 0.478, 0.806, 0.556, 0.201, 0.801, 
    0.348, 1.396, 0.552, 0.384, 0.615, 0.499, 0.819, 0.954, 0.943, 
    0.956, 0.323, 0.706, 0.699, 0.9, 1.156, 1.436, 1.115, 0.762, 
    0.258, 1.421, 0.644, 1.349, 0.251, 0.735, 0.479, 1.055, 1.395, 
    1.062, 1.155, 0.869, 0.436, 0.415, 0.745, 1.247, 0.21, 0.879, 
    0.776, 0.747, 0.835, 0.609, 0.733, 0.563, 1.067, 1.436, 0.679, 
    1.497, 1.385, 1.087, 1.286, 0.503, 0.738, 0.504, 0.665, 1.421, 
    1.288, 0.691, 0.972, 0.467, 0.425, 0.406, 0.862, 0.749, 0.935, 
    0.291, 0.444, 1.118, 1.048, 0.886, 0.982, 0.578, 1.402, 0.778, 
    1.139, 0.804, 0.618, 1.147, 0.594, 0.984, 0.986, 0.941, 0.794, 
    0.323, 1.41, 0.902, 0.417)), row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Many thanks for that approach. It looks promising, but however, I receive an error message like the following:
```error message xxx[[2]] = subscript out of bounds:```(original message was in German: " Fehler in xxx[[2]] : Indizierung außerhalb der Grenzen". 
Do you know what can cause that? (I don't understand the error message).

Comment: It is saying that after splitting by group there is not a second group

Comment: thanks. It was the grouping variable that needed to be factorized. now it works. Thanks again!

Comment: the mentioned package ```srvyr``` also has implemented a function for that called ```srvyr::survey_mean```. But anyhow, I was not able to apply it in the above mentioned content. Maybe you would like to share your idea to implement this as it was intended by my first question? Thanks in advance, if so.

Comment: Glad you figured it out (that's why I made sure I provided an example of the data I used.  No thank you to spending anymore time trying to understand the `survey_mean` function.  You may want to ask the package author or post a different question being more explicit about what you want.  As far as I can tell it produces means but offers no options to run weighted t.test